# overflow numbers to another cell in excel

Tags: excel, split, overflow, cells

Here is what is going on. I am needing to simplify my payroll worksheet. What I want to do for Column D is input actual hours worked with D15 summing all hours up to 40 hours. After 40 hours of course overtime is applied to our employees pay, so is there any way that when 40 is reached in D15, that when I input hours let’s say in D10, that the difference is automatically flowed over to E10? Column E would still auto sum to E15. Please refrain from editing my question. [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in E2 and copy/drag down:

```
=IF(D2<>"",IF(SUM($D$1:D2)>40,MIN(D2,SUM($D$1:D2)-40),0),"")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, i am going to post follup questions in a little bit. this solves 1/3 of my issue and it does work.